# Regedit Hex code isn't working for VBA IDE color change?

Tags: vba

I already tried the github post for the program that selects your VBE7.DLL and it didn't work. Last time I tried this, I utilized HEX modification in REGEDIT. This time around, these codes aren't working.

```
Dark Theme

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common

CodeBackColors 2 14 4 14 15 2 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 

CodeForeColors 13 4 12 0 6 15 9 6 0 11 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

supposed to be this:

[image]

but ends up looking like this with the hex code:

[image]